# Preview the razor design without running the app

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to code Blazor.  I find it really annoying that I have to run the app in order to see the screen design.  **Does anyone know if there's a WYSIWYG tool or feature, so that I can look at the screen design w/o running the app?**  Thanks!

Comment: I generally treat the Blazor component work and the layout as separate concerns.Layout and appearance is just HTML and CSS. I have a VS Code app with `.html` and `.css` files in that I use. Once the layout works reasonable well I copy to the Blazor app. I also use `dotnet watch run` to view the app and it recompiles and reloads in real time

Answer (score 0):

So since there's known, I have been doing this way...and so far my productivity is higher than running the app.  Since I am constructing smaller Razor components, I have been constructing the styling on Codeply and move the styling back to VS once it's confirmed working.  Pretty similar to what Quango has suggested.  Still wishing there's a WYSIWYG feature from VS.